# Dash between elements of a list

Tags: html, css, list

this is my first question here so my apologies if this has been answer somewhere else, I could't find any related entry.

Basically I have an horizontal list that has some dashes between the elements. How do I target and remove these dashes?

here is the code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5rbkbm5w/1/

Comment: It's helpful to post your relevant code on SO (or whatever forum/QA site you're asking on) because JSFiddle (or whatever external site) MIGHT change, causing your question to have less useful/less complete information. That's more important for helping future web-searchers than anything, but it's worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>` tags are not closed, causing white space to be underlined, thus showing the underline for *seemingly* no reason.

Close your tags:
<li><a href="#">Maps`</a>`</li>

Comment: Thanks Jakar, I completely forgot about this question since I moved to another project. But yes, it was very helpful!